# Weinre drops connection almost instantly after connecting with PhoneGap 3.1 and Windows Phone 8

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, weinre

I'm using a framework called [Lavaca](https://github.com/mutualmobile/lavaca-starter) for the HTML/Javascript/css portions of the project.
And if I add in [Weinre](http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/docs/latest/) to the mix with their basic render one single page example on Windows Phone 8 I see the device connect to Weinre and then instantly drop the connection.

If I run the test simple starter project from Cordova/PhoneGap Weinre has staid connected as long as I've needed it to.

There are previous questions here on Stack Overflow for Weinre dropping on WP8 that are from the beginning of 2013 and I've verified that the patch recommended is being used. (The very latest version of Weinre from npm).

I don't really know where to start looking for why it drops the connection, especially since I haven't been able to find any good way of seeing what is going on in the simulator/on the device. I've seen that Visual Studio gives me a very bare bones log of what's going on:

[image: Screenshot from Visual Studio]

Anyone got a suggestion for where I could start looking or how to turn on better logging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tracked down that this is a bug somewhere within WP8 when using `history.replaceState`.

The bug is now reported with Cordova as [CB-5219](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-5219).